# In what form does proton give energy to electron?

Tags: atoms

According to Bohr, electron revolves around the nucleus because of force of attraction between electron and proton. This force of attraction gives energy to the electron. So my question is this that- In which form does this electron get the energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that the Bohr model of the atom [has some shortcomings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model#Shortcomings). Physicists have developed more accurate models since this one. But let's ignore them for this.

From the wording of your question I believe you are curious about the nature of energy when the electron is in a uniform circular orbit. That is, no energy transitions. (In modern language, you are restricting yourself to a single atomic energy level.) Is this correct? If so, read on.

If you apply the classical idea of a force on an object moving in a uniform circular orbit, you'll find that the corresponding force does not do any work. This is because the force and velocity are perpendicular. (If this sounds unfamiliar, look up the dot-product definition of work.) No work, no energy change. So I think your premise is not correct: The force by the proton on the electron does not "give" energy.

Answer (score 0):

The force between the electron and proton is electrostatic. The electron has a negative charge and the proton has a positive charge.

Answer (score 0):

(Not being able to comment is very annoying!)

Why do you think 'This force of attraction gives energy to the electron' / what exactly do you mean by that?

The fact that both particles are electrically charged sets up an electrostatic field, which in turn gives a term in the potential energy of each particle.

In the Bohr model the energy of the electon is it's kinetic energy and it's electrostatic potential energy.
$$ E(r) = T + U(r) = \frac{1}{2}m_ev^2 - \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Z e^2}{r} $$
where $Z$ is the number of charges that the nucleus has, 1 for a proton.